# Rails cause method not found error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, counter, culture

I created Rails 5.1.2 app and deployed to Heroku.

At local, everything is all right, but when deployed to Heroku, below errors occured at starting puma.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `counter_culture' for #<Class:0x00000003296690> (NoMethodError)
```

I specified ruby version to 2.4.1 in my Gemfile,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.1'
```

and heroku cli returns ruby version as below.

```
heroku run "ruby -v"
Running ruby -v on ⬢ my-app... up, run.1200 (Free)
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

but logs from puma says that

```
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/
```

and cannot find method of counter_culture gem.

Someone knows how to resolve this error?

When testing by Heroku CI, this error was not caused.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` on heroku?

Comment: try installing it for production gem 'counter_culture', '~> 1.0'

Comment: post your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing it out.

I put `gem 'counter_culture'` into `group :development, :test`.
It's mistake.

Thanks and Sorry for bother you.
Cheers!